# How should I implement "add" interpreter in scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, interpreter, type-mismatch

I am implementing scala interpreter and I have some problem

I have value class as followed in `Value.scala`:

```
case class IntV(value: Int) extends Value
```

Also I have followed class in file `Expr.scala`:

```
case class IntE(value: Int) extends Expr
case class Add(left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr
```

When I implemented Int interpreter as followed:

```
case IntE(value)=>IntV(value)
```

It worked well but when I implemented add interpreter(which does addition like 3+4=7)as followed:

```
case Add(left, right)=>IntV(left)+IntV(right)
```

It returns error which says for variable left and right, it requires `Int` but it found `expr`.
What did I do wrong? What should I do to get correct return?

Comment: think about what the error means and you will find the answer. Add has 2 values of type Expr. When you pattern match on Add , the way you did , all you know is it is an Expr. You do not know more than that. Can every Expr be converted to an IntV?

Answer (score 3):

You should call interpreter recursively.

For example

```
sealed trait Value
case class IntV(value: Int) extends Value 

sealed trait Expr
case class IntE(value: Int) extends Expr
case class Add(left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr

def interpret(expr: Expr): Value = expr match {
  case IntE(value)      => IntV(value)
  case Add(left, right) => (interpret(left), interpret(right)) match {
    case (IntV(v1), IntV(v2)) => IntV(v1 + v2)
  }
}

interpret(IntE(1)) // IntV(1)
interpret(Add(IntE(3), IntE(4))) // IntV(7)
```

Or with a defined method `+` for `IntV`

```
sealed trait Value
case class IntV(value: Int) extends Value {
  def +(other: IntV): IntV = IntV(value + other.value)
}

sealed trait Expr
case class IntE(value: Int) extends Expr
case class Add(left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr

def interpret(expr: Expr): Value = expr match {
  case IntE(value)      => IntV(value)
  case Add(left, right) => (interpret(left), interpret(right)) match {
    case (v1: IntV, v2: IntV) => v1 + v2
  }
}
```