# How should I implement scala interpreter for tuple?

Tags: scala, interpreter, type-mismatch

I'm implementing scala interpreter and I have some problem.

To begin with, I want to implement `tuple` class

In my `Value.scala`, followed class exist:

```
case class TupleV(values: List[Type]) extends Value
```

Also, in my `Expr.scala`, followed class exist

```
case class TupleE(expressions: List[Type] extends Expr
```

`Type` is also in `Expr.scala` as followed:

```
sealed trait Type
case object IntT extends Type
case object BooleanT extends Type
case object TupleT extends Type
case object ListT extends Type
case object FunctionT extends Type
```

So, I implemented as followed:

```
case TupleE(values)=>TupleV(values)
```

but it says List[Expr] found, List[Value] is required. What is the problem in my code? what should I to to fix it?

Also I tried to implement in different way using ConsE and ConsV class which enable me to divide list into head and tail:

```
case class ConsE(head: Expr, tail: Expr) extends Expr//in Expr.scala
case class ConsV(head: Value, tail: Value) extends Value//in Value.scala
case ConsE(head, tail)=>ConsV(interp(head), interp(tail)//my implementation for ConsV interpreter&works well now
```

Using that, I tried

```
case TupleE(expression)=>expression match{
  case ConsE(head, tail)=>ConsV(head, tail)
}
```

But it returns: "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type" error for ConsE. How should I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089412/how-should-i-implement-add-interpreter-in-scala

Comment: What is `Type`? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Shouldn't it be `TupleV(values: List[Value]) extends Value` and `TupleE(values: List[Expr]) extends Expr`?

Comment: Please provide real code that shows the error, rather than snippets with syntax errors. At very least you need to show that `match` that contains that `case` statement.

Comment: Not sure whether this is still relevant but I found the definition of `Type` in your [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101444/i-have-some-problems-with-implementing-scala-interpreter) question `sealed trait Type`
`case object IntT extends Type` ...

Comment: That is same Type for this question. As someone told me to focus on only one question, I changed the format of question. I also edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
case class TupleV(values: List[Type]) extends Value

case class TupleE(expressions: List[Type]) extends Expr
```

with

```
case class TupleV(values: List[Value]) extends Value 

case class TupleE(expressions: List[Expr]) extends Expr
```

(Are those definitions given to you in an exercise or are they your own definitions that you can modify?)

Based on

```
case TupleE(values)=>TupleV(values)
```

you're writing interpreter

```
def interpret(expr: Expr): Value
```

i.e. continue what you started in [How should I implement "add" interpreter in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089412/how-should-i-implement-add-interpreter-in-scala)

Then the definitions of `TupleV`, `TupleE` should be latter above. Former their definitions above make less sense to me.

`Type` is needed when you typecheck an `Expr`

```
def typecheck(expr: Expr): Type // or Option[Type]
```

Then you'll have one more hierarchy

```
case class TupleT(types: List[Type]) extends Type
```

---

> So, I implemented as followed:
>
> ```
> case TupleE(values)=>TupleV(values)
> ```
>
> but it says List[Expr] found, List[Value] is required. What is the
> problem in my code? what should I to to fix it?

This is irreproducible. The code compiles

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KWlyFOYDRHOgN6UibVY1pw

> Using that, I tried
>
> ```
>  case TupleE(expression)=>expression match{   
>    case ConsE(head, tail)=>ConsV(head, tail)
>  }
> ```
>
> But it returns: "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type"
> error for ConsE.

This error is clear: in `TupleE(expression)` `expression` has type `List[Type]`, it can't match `ConsE`, it can match only ordinary scala `List`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, those definition for case class TupleV and TupleE are provided for excercise and I cant change it.

Comment: In this exercise, it contains ConsE function which allows me to divide list into head and tail which is written as 
case ConsE(head, tail)=>ConsV(interp(head), interp(tail)) 
I tried to use this interpreter to divide the tuple but it didnt work well. Will I be able to solve this with this interpreter?

Comment: @Chhong39 Then you should provide reproducible code in your question. Currently can't reproduce "`List[Expr]` found, `List[Value]` is required". The code compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xKlWbV9uRSiqJKxBVKvDUA

Comment: @Chhong39 Definitions of `ConsE`, `ConsV` and other definitions should be in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for investing time. I added those definitions and what I tried to do.